# Folder action not triggering shell script

Tags: bash, shell, directory, osx-elcapitan, automator

I have some software that exports a file called `My Library.bib` to a folder called `thesis`. Assume that the name of the exported file is fixed. Every time I export such a file, I want to:

1. Delete any old files called `MyLibrary.bib` if they exist.
2. Remove the space from this new file so that it becomes the up-to-date `MyLibrary.bib`.

I've tried making an Automator 'folder action' as follows:

[image: folder action]

... However, while the shell script works perfectly if run manually, the folder action itself never appears to trigger.

Folder actions are nonetheless enabled (see below settings), and other folder actions do seem to work.

[image: folder actions setup]

Summarily, I just want any files named `My Library.bib` entering the `thesis` folder (at any time, automatically) to become renamed to `MyLibrary.bib`, replacing any existing `MyLibrary.bib` files. Any ideas what's going wrong, or how else to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you save the script in `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell No - it autosaved to ``~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions`` (I've heard that the default location changed over versions of Mac OS X). However, trying it in your suggested path also has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the "**Run Shell Script**" action, the current directory is the **Home** folder, not the "**thesis**" folder.

So, you must use the `cd` command to change the current directory

Informations:

- The "**Get Folder Content**" action is useless for what you want to do,
  you can remove it.
- The `rm` command is not necessary, you can use the `mv -f` to
  overwrite an existing file

---

```
read firstLine ### get the path of the first dropped item
myDir=$(dirname "$firstLine") ### get the parent (this folder action)
cd "$myDir" && if [ -f "My Library.bib" ]; then 
    mv -f "My Library.bib" "MyLibrary.bib"
fi
```

Comment: The `if`-statement is likewise useless. Just `mv -f "My Library.bib" "MyLibrary.bib"`.

Comment: @Kusalananda,  Yes, but the workflow put an error in the log file when no such file  --> `FolderActionsDispatcher[365]: error: {}`